# Set day and month format, but not their order

Tags: c#, datetime

I know about Datetime formats. "dd" stands for day from 01 to 31, "MM" - the month from 01 through 12. I need this format. But if I write "dd MM"(in my case in ToString() method) it will always put day before the month. How can I set this format(dd and MM) without changing the order(what comes first - day or month) from current locale? So if in current culture day comes first I want to receive "20 08 2012"(separator doesn't matter here), and if month comes first - "08 20 2012"

Comment: `myDate.ToString("MM dd")` - the month will appear before the day. Unless you mean something else?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Isn't "without changing the order(what comes first - day or month) from current locale" part not clear? I added example.

Comment: Pethaps use [`DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthDayPattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthdaypattern.aspx)?

Comment: Sorry still not clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I need to make that day and month will be two digits, but I don't want to set what comes first - day or month

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`MonthDayPattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthdaypattern.aspx) from the current locale to get the relative order of the two items, and then construct either `dd MM` or `MM dd`:

```
var mdp = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthDayPattern;
string pattern = mdp.IndexOf('M') < mdp.IndexOf('d') ? "MM dd" : "dd MM";
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the culture's [MonthDayPattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthdaypattern.aspx). Maybe you can customize it to your needs, e.g.

```
string FormatWithMonthDayPattern(DateTime dateTime, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    var pattern = cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.MonthDayPattern;
    return dateTime.ToString(Regex.Replace(pattern, "M+", "MM"));
}

var result1 = FormatWithMonthDayPattern(DateTime.Now, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
// result1 == "08 20"

var result2 = FormatWithMonthDayPattern(DateTime.Now, new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
// result2 == "20 08"
```

Comment: Pity that A cannot accept two answers, so I just can vote you up, thanks!